# Call to a member function makeAdmin() on null

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to write a function that updates a users record to make them and admin. But I'm getting this error and I'm not sure how to remedy it. I've looked around at other posts and none of them seem to apply to my situation.

**Controller**

```
 public function make_admin ($post){
        $this->load->model('User_model');
        $post = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);
        $cleanPost = $this->security->xss_clean($post);
        $this->user_model->makeAdmin($cleanPost);
    }
```

**Model**

```
 public function makeAdmin($post)
{
    $data = array(
           'role' => $this->role[1]
        );
    $this->db->where('id', $post['user_id']);
    $this->db->update('users', $data); 
    $success = $this->db->affected_rows(); 

    if(!$success){
        error_log('Unable to updateUserInfo('.$post['user_id'].')');
        return false;
    }

    $user_info = $this->getUserInfo($post['user_id']); 
    return $user_info; 
}
```

Comment: show your error meassage.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
$this->user_model->makeAdmin($cleanPost);
```

to this

```
$this->User_model->makeAdmin($cleanPost);
```

Comment: That worked but now I'm getting these errors

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Admin::$role

Filename: core/Model.php

Line Number: 77

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Illegal string offset 'user_id'

Filename: models/User_model.php

Line Number: 162

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Illegal string offset 'user_id'

Filename: models/User_model.php

Line Number: 167

Comment: use this in controller`$post = $this->input->post('user_id');` and use this your model`$this->db->where('id', $post);`

Comment: Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Admin::$role

Filename: core/Model.php

Line Number: 77

Comment: check this `var_dump($data);` in your model

Comment: array(1) { ["role"]=> NULL }

Comment: post your model class

Comment: I just figured it out. role was supposed to be roles

Comment: No it's don't updating to the DB

Comment: When ever try to click the link to run the function it just displays a white screen

Comment: the make_Admin function in the controller

Answer (score 0):

You should write

```
$this->User_model->makeAdmin($cleanPost);
```

CI syntax is

```
$this->load->model('Model_name');

$this->Model_name->function();
```

If you would like your model assigned to a different object name you can specify it via the second parameter of the loading function:

```
$this->load->model('Model_name', 'fubar');

$this->fubar->function();
```

Hope it will help you :)